# Upload file into sharepoint document library using REST

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, rest

I am developing a sharepoint-hosted application now it can upload files to a document library  using REST api  can anybody help me to achieve this.

Answer (score 8):

Too many solutions are in the web. Please bother to search before asking!

```
function uploadDocument() {
    if (!window.FileReader) {
        alert("This browser does not support the HTML5 File APIs");
        return;
    }

    var element = document.getElementById("uploadInput");
    var file = element.files[0];
    var parts = element.value.split("\\");
    var fileName = parts[parts.length - 1];

    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (e) {
        addItem(e.target.result, fileName);
    }
    reader.onerror = function (e) {
        alert(e.target.error);
    }
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);

    function addItem(buffer, fileName) {
        var call = uploadDocument(buffer, fileName);
        call.done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            var call2 = getItem(data.d);
            call2.done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                var item = data.d;
                var call3 = updateItemFields(item);
                call3.done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    var div = jQuery("#message");
                    div.text("Item added");
                });
                call3.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    failHandler(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);
                });
            });
            call2.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                failHandler(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);
            });
        });
        call.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            failHandler(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);
        });
    }

    function uploadDocument(buffer, fileName) {
        var url = String.format(
            "{0}/_api/Web/Lists/getByTitle('Project Documents')/RootFolder/Files/Add(url='{1}', overwrite=true)",
            _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl, fileName);
        var call = jQuery.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: "POST",
            data: buffer,
            processData: false,
            headers: {
                Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose",
                "X-RequestDigest": jQuery("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
                "Content-Length": buffer.byteLength
            }
        });

        return call;
    }

    function getItem(file) {
        var call = jQuery.ajax({
            url: file.ListItemAllFields.__deferred.uri,
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            headers: {
                Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"
            }
        });

        return call;
    }

    function updateItemFields(item) {
        var now = new Date();
        var call = jQuery.ajax({
            url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl +
                "/_api/Web/Lists/getByTitle('Project Documents')/Items(" +
                item.Id + ")",
            type: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify({
                "__metadata": { type: "SP.Data.Project_x0020_DocumentsItem" },
                Year: now.getFullYear()
            }),
            headers: {
                Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose",
                "Content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                "X-RequestDigest": jQuery("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
                "IF-MATCH": item.__metadata.etag,
                "X-Http-Method": "MERGE"
            }
        });

        return call;
    }

    function failHandler(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        var response = JSON.parse(jqXHR.responseText);
        var message = response ? response.error.message.value : textStatus;
        alert("Call failed. Error: " + message);
    }
}
```

The example taken from [here](http://geekswithblogs.net/ThorvaldBoe/archive/2014/06/06/how-to-upload-files-to-a-sharepoint-2013-document-library.aspx)

Comment: I'd tried already this code but it returns this problem :  403 (Forbidden)

Comment: what is is the actual error? show whole error message over here. reason could be the URL you are posting your data. Show your code in your question

Comment: I figure out what's the problem. now this.... the document library where i want to upload the files  is located 
at this a specified site 'https://domain.sharepoint.com/Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx'
and i'm running my application at 'https://domain.sharepoint.com/myapp'
there's no problem when i tried to upload the files on the
https://domain.sharepoint.com/myapp/Documents/' now the issue is how to upload files at that site above using your code..

Comment: yes you can upload from sub site to root site. in that case you url should be 'domain.sharepoint.com/Documents'. You can run your application from anywhere...... it does not matter. only the url matters

Comment: var url = String.format(
{0}/_api/Web/Lists/getByTitle('Documents')/RootFolder/Files/Add(url='{1}', overwrite=true)",
shptService.hostWebUrl, fileName);

where shptService.hostWebUrl is 'domain.sharepoint.com/Documents'
but i'm having then the 403 forbidden error .

Comment: Browser is crashed if file size is around 100MB + as soon as POST method is sent from addFileToFolder is called

Answer (score 1):

As you're getting a 403 error, You are facing the permissions issue, you need to give appropriate permissions in your app's app.manifest file.